# Wrap texts in table with Python

Tags: python

I'm printing out words and their meanings in pairs with Python 2.7.9. I stored the words in a list, and meanings in another. 
Suppose I've defined:

```
word=['a','the','go','python']    
meaning=['meaning1','meaning2','veryveryveryveryveryverylongmeaning3','meaning4']
```

I want to get the output like:

```
a      meaning1
the    meaning2
go     veryveryveryveryvery
       verylongmeaning3
python meaning4
```

The problem is the textwrap module in std lib only breaks the long 'meaning' of word to nested list **without adding a new line correspondingly in the word list**. I don't know after wrapping how many lines there are in the 'meaning', either. Any other coding tricks?

Comment: Please give the Minimal, Complete code of your question.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, or quite what you're trying to do. Can you elaborate? Some sample input and out would help, especially a demonstration of what the code is doing wrong.

Comment: What's sample output of this `meaning=map(lambda x:textwrap.wrap(x),meaning)`

Comment: @Cyphase Hi, I just wanna print word with its corresponding meaning (in code word[i] and meaning[i]) as a table, but sometimes the meaning is too long that I want to wrap the text into a new line. Clear enough now?

Comment: The lookup code is unimportant, try reducing the question to a simple statement of the problem.

Comment: @luoluo, typically, it returns [['meaning1'], ['meaning2'], ['veryveryve', 'ryveryvery', 'veryveryve', 'ryveryvery', 'veryveryve', 'ryveryvery', 'veryverylo', 'ngmeaning3'], ['meaning4']], I've added some 'very's though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `textwrap.wrap()` does; it returns a list of lines, without newlines at the end. It's up to you to do whatever you need to with that.

As an aside, you should probably use a `dict` for the words and meanings, or an `OrderedDict` if you want to keep the order.

```
import textwrap

from collections import OrderedDict

words = ['a', 'the', 'go', 'python']
meanings = ['meaning1', 'meaning2', 'meaning3',
            'Python is a programming language that lets you work more quickly '
            'and integrate your systems more effectively. You can learn to '
            'use Python and see almost immediate gains in productivity and '
            'lower maintenance costs.']

wrapped_meanings = ['\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(meaning)) for meaning in meanings]

dictionary = OrderedDict(zip(words, wrapped_meanings))

for word, meaning in dictionary.items():
    print word
    print meaning
    print
```

Output:

```
a
meaning1

the
meaning2

go
meaning3

python
Python is a programming language that lets you work more quickly and
integrate your systems more effectively. You can learn to use Python
and see almost immediate gains in productivity and lower maintenance
costs.
```

Comment: So subtle to use join method!

Answer (score 1):

use `enumerate` to go through the list, `format` to format your string output, `join` to merge the meanings.

```
word=['a','the','go','python']    
meaning= [['meaning1'], ['meaning2'], ['veryveryve', 'ryveryvery', 'veryveryve', 'ryveryvery', 'veryveryve', 'ryveryvery', 'veryverylo', 'ngmeaning3'], ['meaning4']]
for i, value in enumerate(word):
    print "{}\t{}".format(value, "\n\t".join(meaning[i]))
```

## output

```
a   meaning1
the meaning2
go  veryveryve
    ryveryvery
    veryveryve
    ryveryvery
    veryveryve
    ryveryvery
    veryverylo
    ngmeaning3
python  meaning4
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be unable to concatenate list and str

```
print str(word[i])+'\t'+str(meaning[i])
```